# Laravel Socialite user always null

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

i work on a project and i need to use google oauth2.0 but It's always send a null user. I installed a new laravel 8.5 project to be sure and it's always the same situationeven if i use github or facebook instead of google.

My environment config :
**OS**: Parrot Ara (Debian Bullseye)
**PHP version** : 8.0 
**Laravel version** : 8.5

in routes/web.php

```
Route::get("connexion/google/redirect", function(){
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
})->name("google.redirect");
Route::get("connexion/google/callback", function(){
     dd(Socialite::driver('google'));
});
```

in config/services.php

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
'github' => [
    'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GITHUB_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
```

the return of `dd(Socialite::driver('google'));` (i remove client secret and id)

```
Laravel\Socialite\Two\GoogleProvider {#294 ▼
  #scopeSeparator: " "
  #scopes: array:3 [▶]
  #request: Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▶}
  #httpClient: null
  #clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  #clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  #redirectUrl: "http://localhost:8000/connexion/google/callback"
  #parameters: []
  #encodingType: 1
  #stateless: false
  #usesPKCE: false
  #guzzle: []
  #user: null
}
```

Comment: please, provide auth middleware components configuration

Comment: Nothing special a this level it's the default config

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @RyanGoss have you got this working?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @LucasLaurens not now :-(

Comment: Any news on this? Got the same issue